# IOS/Objective-C:Add another variable to a mutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have a simple array of strings such as the following:

```
myArray *NSArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"chevy", @"ford", @"toyota", nil];
```

I want to add another dimension to the array such as `@"1",@"2",@"3"` in order to keep track of the order.

Is there a simple way to do this?

**Edit**

I found answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498756/convert-nsarray-to-twodimensional-array).  Create 2nd array and employ loop:

```
//For your 2D array
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[homePlayersArray count]];

//populate as required
for(int i=0;i<[homePlayersArray count];i++){
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    [secondArray addObject:tempArray];
}
```

Comment: what type of output you expect

Comment: They're already in order...explain your problem in more detail.

Comment: This array is being used as a datasource for a table.  I wish to let the user reorder the table.  I need an order number variable to keep track of how the user rearranges the table. The elements you see above, chevy, ford, toyota are actually collected from textfields.  However, at a later point in the code I want to add another variable for the order number to facilitate reordering.  Hence question, how do you add a new variable/dimension to an array.  Note, they do not have to be key value.  I can just use the index of the array to link them up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use two arrays (as per your edit to the question), which brings with it the possibility of getting the two out of sync with each other, consider using an array of dictionaries.

For example, your array might start out as:

```
NSArray *myArray = @[ @{ @"make" : @"chevy" }.mutableCopy,
                      @{ @"make" : @"ford" }.mutableCopy,
                      @{ @"make" : @"toyota" }.mutableCopy
                   ];
```

This produces you an `NSArray` (immutable) of `NSMutableDictionary` (mutable) - so you have the ordering of an array and the flexibility of a mutable dictionary to add your extra variable. For example to add an order number of `106249` to the first entry you could use:

```
NSMutableDictionary *entry = (NSMutableDictionary *)myArray[0];
entry[@"orderNumber"] = @106249;
```

If you use the *lightweight generics* feature of Objective-C you can define your array as:

```
NSArray <NSMutableDictionary *> *myArray = @[ ... ];
```

This informs the compiler that the array will only contain mutable dictionaries, which in turn allows setting the order number to become just:

```
myArray[0][@"orderNumber"] = @106249;
```

without needing to use any casts.

Your next step to reduce errors is to define constants for the keys:

```
const NSString *kMake = @"make";
const NSString *kOrderNumber = @"orderNumber";
```

and the final sample code looks like:

```
NSArray <NSMutableDictionary *> *myArray
   = @[ @{ kMake : @"chevy" }.mutableCopy,
        @{ kMake : @"ford" }.mutableCopy,
        @{ kMake : @"toyota" }.mutableCopy
     ];

myArray[0][kOrderNumber] = @106249;
```

You can of course also make the array itself mutable should you need to add new entries to it. And the next stage is to define your own class with `make` and `orderNumber` properties rather than use dictionaries.

HTH

Comment: Thank you for your thoughtful answer in contrast to the other answers which missed the point of the question. This is probably a better way to do it so I wlil market it correct.  Also +1 for civility!  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are those supposed to key-value pairs? If so, better use NSDictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = @{ @"1" : @"chevy", @"2" : @"ford", @"3" : @"toyota"};
```

Comment: They are not key value pairs.  I need to add the second dimension at a later point in the code.  In other words I want to convert a one dimensional array into a two dimensional array.

Comment: Not really sure what are you trying to achieve. Can you elaborate or show an example?

Answer (score 0):

Create `NSDictionary` instead of `NSArray`

```
NSDictionary *dictionaryOfCars = @{ @"1" : @"chevy", @"2" : @"ford", @"3" : @"toyota"};
```

You can access any item in dictionary using :

```
id item = [dictionaryOfCars objectForKey:@"1"];// item  = @"chevy"
```

Comment: Not key value pairs.  I just want to add a second dimension at a later point in the code.  Otherwise, I would add them all at once.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way to fix this is to create a second array and then loop through the records as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20498756/convert-nsarray-to-twodimensional-array).  For a more complicated way that has some advantages, see CRD's answer.  The other answers do not address the question.

```
//For your 2D array
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:[homePlayersArray count]];

//populate as required
for(int i=0;i<[homePlayersArray count];i++){
    NSArray *tempArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[homePlayersArray objectAtIndex:i],[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], nil];
    [secondArray addObject:tempArray];
}
```