# Objective C, maze generation and 2D arrays

Tags: objective-c, multidimensional-array, maze

I need to generate a random maze with given width and height. I could do this in Perl with Depth-first search algorithm, in which I use 2D arrays, something like this:

```
    for my $i (0 .. $h - 1) {
        for my $j (0 .. $w - 1) {
            push @{ $cell[$i] }, '1';
        }
        push @{ $cell[$i] }, '0';
    }
    for my $i (0 .. $w) {
        $cell[$h][$i] = '';
    }
```

While in Objective C, there's no 2D array. I'm kind of lost now. What is the equivalent of 2D array in Objective C so that I pretty much can use the same data structure as in Perl?
Thanks.

Comment: Use arrays inside arrays:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4362740/creating-a-two-dimensional-array-in-objective-c

Comment: And have a refresher on data structures - this should be kind of obvious.

Comment: Objective-C is merely a superset of C, so you can use plain old 2D arrays from C like this: `int twoDimArray[][]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use Objective-C style array:

```
NSMutableArray *cell = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:h];
for (int i=0; i<h; ++i) {
    NSMutableArray *row = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:w];
    for (int j=0; j<w; ++j) {
        // use a random number
        [row addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:rand()]];
    }
    // add one row
    [cell addObject:row];
}
```

Another way is just to use C style array:

```
int **cell = malloc(h*sizeof(int *));
for (int i=0; i<h; ++i) {
    cell[i] = malloc(w*sizeof(int));
    for (int j=0; j<w; ++j) {
        cell[i][j] = rand();
    }
}

// after you used it remeber to free it
for (int i=0; i<h; ++i) {
    free(cell[i]);
}
free(cell);
cell = NULL;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this github library to generate maze.
https://github.com/DoubleEqual/MazeGenerator-tool
The result looks like this for 24x24 maze:
[image]

Comment: The Maze Generator Tool code have a copyright or is free to use?

Answer (score 0):

A 2-Dimentional or N-Dimentional arrays are nothing but a way to store the data. If you want a 2-D array its fairly simple, but little bit tricky in obj-c, you have to creates 2nd level arrays, then insert it into first level.

See the code below :

```
NSMutableArray *twoDArray = [NSMutableArray new]; //this is first level

//below are second level arrays inserted in index 0 to 2.
[twoDArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"00",@"01",@"02",nil] atIndex:0];
[twoDArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"10",@"11",@"12",nil] atIndex:1];
[twoDArray insertObject:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"20",@"21",@"22",nil] atIndex:2];
```